# php: trying to find an equivalent of map

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm struggling to build an object of objects, instead of an array of objects, (that works but is less easy to use later with json)

use http://writecodeonline.com/php/ for testing it

```
$a = Array();
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->key = "name";
$obj->value = "durant";
array_push($a, $obj);

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->key = "friend";
$obj->value = "johns";
array_push($a, $obj);

$preds = Array();
foreach( $a as $v ){
$item = Array(); // new stdClass(); 
$item[$v->key] = $v->value; // ^  doesn't work
array_push($preds, $item);
}
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->key = "data";
$obj->value = $preds;
array_push($a, $obj);

//var_dump($a);

echo(json_encode($a[2]->value));  // returns: [{"name":"durant"},{"friend":"johns"}]
```

I would like to be able to easily perform $arr['name'] or  $arr['friend']

**EDIT**:  works like that (thx Dani): I'm totally noob to Php, so If someone can explain (the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT opts did not solved it)

```
$a = Array();
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->key = "name";
$obj->value = "durant";
array_push($a, $obj);

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->key = "friend";
$obj->value = "johns";
array_push($a, $obj);

$preds = new stdClass();
foreach( $a as $v ){
$k = $v->key;
$preds->$k = $v->value;
}
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->key = "data";
$obj->value = $preds;
array_push($a, $obj);

echo(json_encode($a[2]->value)); // returns: {"name":"durant", "friend":"johns"}
```

Comment: You want to produce objects, but then you're using arrays in your code...

Comment: I believe op is asking for help to convert it

Comment: @OP object of objects looks like this: `{a:{b:3, c:4}, b:{f:5, d:10}}`

Comment: What do you want to use this for? Seen as `{{"tob":"durant"},{"caty":"johns"}}` isn't valid JSON, and you're using json_encode.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to have an object that stores several objects, but without clear identifiers which property of the object is what you have not valid JSON.

Comment: that's right, I'm tired  I would like a sort of String,String map in json, what is the closer?

Comment: How is encoded a python dictionnary of Strings or a Java Map<String, String> in json?

Comment: An ordinary PHP object or associative array is equivalent to a Java Map<String, Object> - which is to say, the values can be anything (including strings).  Caveat: PHP may behave strangely if a string key in an array could be interpreted as a number.

Comment: You can achieve what you want by changing `echo(json_encode($a[2]->value));` to `echo(json_encode((object)$a[2]->value));` in last line.

Comment: See my answer, json_encode($a[2]->value, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable variables:

```
$name = 'bar';
$foo->$name = 123; 
// same as:
$foo->bar = 123;
```

Comment: thx I've no idea why but it works (see edited topic), u saved my day

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but what you're trying to accomplish can be done with simple PHP (associative) arrays, which you may compare to Ruby's hashes or JavaScript's objects:

```
$myArray = array('foo' => 'bar');
```

Or, in PHP 5.4 syntax:

```
$myArray = ['foo' => 'bar']
```

Also, as others said, `{{"tob":"durant"},{"caty":"johns"}}` isn't a valid object since it doesn't have keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast an associative array to an object, so if you want quick and easy object initialization, you can use array syntax and then cast it:

```
$var = (object) array(
    'dit'=>'dat',
    'foo'=>'bar',
);
```

(`{{"tob":"durant"},{"caty":"johns"}}` is invalid JavaScript, so I'm kinda guessing at what you want.  `{0:{"tob":"durant"},1:{"caty":"johns"}}` is what you'll get if you cast an ordinary array to an object.)

Comment: I'm doing a json_encode of it, then a json_decode, and I have this [{"a":"ll"},{"firstname":"johns"},{"lastname":"durant"}], I would like to be able to call $arr['firstname']

Comment: `$arr = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr);`?  That will combine `[{"a":"ll"},{"firstname":"johns"},{"lastname":"durant"}]` into `{"a":"ll","firstname":"johns","lastname":"durant"}` (as an associative array).

Answer (score 0):

When converting to JSON, associative arrays (arrays with at least 1 string key) will always convert to a JSON object.

When converting empty or arrays without string keys (numeric keys), the arrays will always convert to a JSON array [].

In order to make sure empty arrays, or numeric arrays, are too converted to objects, cast them with (object) when passing them as param.

If however you have nested arrays, it is much easier to pass a flag to json_encode like this: **`json_encode($arrNestedArraysAndObjects, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`** (you need > PHP 5.3, which has been out for years).